# How do I properly align my Cartopy maps with the shapefile I am using to clip my data?

Tags: python, plot, maps, cartopy

I am having difficulty generating maps in python using cartopy. The data shows up seemingly accurately, but it is misaligned with the shapefile outline I want to use to clarify the image. I cant seem to get the alignment right. The shapefile on display is the same one I use earlier in the code to ignore the irrelevant surrounding ocean data.

this is the current code I am using to generate my map.  If this is a bad way to plot or there are any suggestions on a simpler/ better way I am willing to rework it and learn a new/better module.

```
##this is the code used to create the clip for the shapefile
ds.rio.set_spatial_dims(x_dim="latitude", y_dim="longitude", inplace=True)
ds.rio.write_crs("epsg:4326", inplace=True)
Africa_Shape = gpd.read_file(r"C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\Thesis\Shapefiles\Madagascar\Madagascar.shx", crs="epsg:4326")

clipped = ds.rio.clip(Africa_Shape.geometry.apply(mapping), Africa_Shape.crs, drop=False)

###and this is the script for the plot

### Plot solar Map

longitude_min = 40
longitude_max = 55
latitude_min = -10
latitude_max = -30
\###Coeff_STAB average

# Generate example data with dimensions (57, 37) as C

sun_CF = map_CF_mean_solar

# Generate X and Y coordinates with any dimensions you want

X = np.linspace(longitude_min, longitude_max, num=sun_CF.shape\[1\]+1)
Y = np.linspace(latitude_min, latitude_max, num=sun_CF.shape\[0\]+1)

# Create a map projection (e.g., PlateCarree for a simple lat/lon plot)

projection = ccrs.PlateCarree()

# Create a figure and axis with Cartopy projection

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'projection': projection}, figsize=(10, 12))

# Plot the data using pcolormesh with shading='flat'

cmap = plt.get_cmap('cividis')  # Choose a colormap (you can change it)
im = ax.pcolormesh(X, Y, sun_CF+1, cmap=cmap, shading='flat',transform = projection, vmin=0, vmax=1)

# Add coastlines, gridlines, and other map features

ax.coastlines()
ax.gridlines()

# Add a colorbar

cbar = plt.colorbar(im, ax=ax, label='Average capacity factor')

# Set plot title and labels

ax.set_title('CF  solar monthly average')
ax.set_xlabel('Longitude')
ax.set_ylabel('Latitude')

# Set the extent of the plot to match your region

ax.set_extent(\[longitude_min, longitude_max, latitude_min, latitude_max\], crs= projection )

# Show the plot

plt.show()
```

[this is the map I generate, ignoring the fact that the data is one colour, any ideas on this misalignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96g6P.png)

Comment: without the data it's impossible to see where things go wrong... If you still search for an alternative package, have a look at [EOmaps](https://github.com/raphaelquast/EOmaps)!